# <a> tags being underlined in Tumblr but cant see why not... not in css

Tags: css, tumblr

ive made this Tumblr blog

(its just a shell at the moment) and ive got my top nav from my website and copied it into the tumblr code to give my blog the same look as my website (unless any one can recomend a better way of doing it ?)

Any way the nav links all appear underlined ive looked all through the external css and the inline css using firebug but still cant see why this is any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Sam

Answer (score 7):

Links are underlined by default.

If you want to get rid of it, target your `a` tags and set the `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: I've just tried to find out in the source code with keyword "underline". So stupid :).

Comment: Vantrung, "stupid" doesn't apply to design & development. Some people may not know as much as you or me, but that makes them uninformed/unknowledgeable, not stupid.

Comment: @vonkly: You must have misunderstood me. The word "stupid" that I used is for myself. Kinda I said "I was so stupid". Is that okay?

Comment: @vantrun, he knows you were talking about yourself. He's saying that its not stupid of you to look for the word "underline". It's a reasonable attempt to find out whats wrong by someone who doesn't know the answer. Nothing stupid about that :P

Comment: @Brandon: Really? But I don't think he's talking 'bout me when he said: "Some people may not know as much as you or me...". Furthermore, I said "So stupid :)" - but not "So stupid". The emoticon made the word meaning change a lot. Do u think so? Well, relax, is your humor absent 2day?

Comment: @Brandon: Well, I think we're going too far. Just stop here, ok?